# wrong format of generated text file in python

Tags: python, text

> I have a big parent list containing many lists of tuples like the small example:
>
> ```
> [
> [('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP')], 
> [('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('EN02', 'EHGT', 'GFT')]
> ]
> ```
>
> My goal is to make a text file in which there would some columns. The columns are the 
>   second tuple of each list in the parent list. The first tuple in all lists are similar 
>   in all nested lists and they would be column names.
>
> I used this code(z is above list)
>
> ```
> rows= [i[1] for i in z]
> ```
>
> to get
>
> ```
> [('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP'), ('EN02', 'EHGT', 'GFT')]
> ```
>
> And this one (which I call it “A”)
>
> ```
> with open('out.txt','w') as f :
>     f.write (' '.join(z[0][0]))
>     for i in rows:
>         f.write (' '.join(i))
> ```
>
> to get the file.  But in the file the columns are not separated like this.

```
id       name   Trans
ENS001   EGSB   TTP
EN02     EHGT   GFT
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing it all on one line, you need to add a newline:

```
rows = (sub[1] for sub in z)


with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    f.write ("{}\n".format(' '.join(z[0][0]))) # add a newline
    for i in rows:
        f.write ("{}\n".format(' '.join(i))) # newline again
```

If you always have three elements in your rows and you want them aligned:

```
rows = [sub[1] for sub in z]


mx_len = 0

for tup in rows:
    mx = len(max(tup[:-1],key=len))
    if mx > mx_len:
        mx_len = mx

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    a, b, c = z[0][0]
    f.write("{:<{mx_len}} {:<{mx_len}} {}\n".format(a, b, c, mx_len=mx_len))
    for a, b, c in rows:
        f.write("{:<{mx_len}} {:<{mx_len}} {}\n".format(a, b, c, mx_len=mx_len))
```

Output:

```
id     name   Trans
ENS001 EGSB   TTP
EN02   EHGT   GFT
```

If the length varies:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(("{:<{mx_len}}"*len(z[0][0])).format(*z[0][0], mx_len=mx_len) + "\n")
    for row in rows:
        f.write(("{:<{mx_len}}"*len(row)).format(*row, mx_len=mx_len) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align column with spaces, first you have to determine what each column's width will be -- presumably the length of the longer header or content of each column, e.g:

```
wids = [len(h) for h in z[0][0]]
for i in rows:
    wids = [max(len(r), w) for w, r in zip(wids, i)]
```

Then on this basis you can prepare a format string, such as

```
fmt = ' '.join('%%%ds' % w for w in wids) + '\n'
```

and finally, you can write things out:

```
with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(fmt % z[0][0])
    for i in rows:
        f.write(fmt % i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be separated by tabs like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab-separated_values_.28TSV.29) you can join on `\t`, rather than `' '`, which you are using. The bottom line of your code would look like `f.write('\t'.join(i))`.

Comment: that is still going to write it all on one line

Comment: the alignment may be required but the newline certainly is otherwise it will be one long line

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think I am focusing on the words "the columns are not separated like this" part.