# export data into file in python

Tags: python, file

I am exporting my data from a list of lists.

when I run the following code

> ```
> with open('out5.txt','w') as f :
>     f.write ('\t'.join(z[0][0]))
>     for i in rows:
>         f.write ('\t'.join(i))
> ```

everything is in the same line but I want a file like this

> ```
> id    name  Trans
>
> ENS001 EGSB  TTP
>
> EN02   EHGT  GFT
> ```

Comment: Is this the same as your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695965/wrong-format-of-generated-text-file-in-python)?

Comment: no. do you have any answer?

Comment: Sure looks like it to me: you've just replaced `' '` with `'\t'`, and changed the name of the output file.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [newline characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) `\n`

```
 f.write('\t'.join(i) + '\n')
```

I would do it like this :

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open('out5.txt','w') as f :
    print(*z[0][0], sep="\t", file=f, end="\n")
    for i in rows:
       print(*i, sep="\t", file=f, end="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a newline after each print to file. You should try this

```
with open('out5.txt','w') as f :
    f.write ('\t'.join(z[0][0]))
    f.write ('\n')
    for i in rows:
        f.write ('\t'.join(i))
        f.write ('\n')
```